# Error when open Performance Point report :Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, performancepoint, bi

When I open a deployed dashboard and report I get below error, see image.

How to solve this issue and why does this happen?

This Sharepoint farm has 6 servers:

- 4 application servers ( two search servers, 1 server running pps and secure store service, one server for central admin and other services)
- 2 wfe servers

[image]

In ULS logs I find below error.

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.SQM.NativeMethods.SqmFEnabled()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.SQM.IsSqmEnabled()
>    at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.ServerCommon.SQMRecorder.CheckForSQM()
>    at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls.ServerConnectionManager.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: why this error occurs and how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

solved by running psconfig wizard in wfe sharepoint servers